# xcode crash uploaded successfully but not visible in crashlytics

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I have integrated crashlytics in my  code. Followed the steps

> Launch the Simulator. Hit Stop in Xcode. Launch your app in the
>   Simulator and cause a crash. Hit Run in Xcode. The crash report will
>   show up and you can see console output indicating that the report has
>   been sent.

I can see that Xcode uploaded crash successfully but not visible in crashlytics. What may be reasons?

Comment: Did you set Fabric in Debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [Check DWARF with dSYM File](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features):

> Double-check in your Build Settings that your Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release

2) [Check if `Fabric.with(\[Crashlytics.self\])` is last line at appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html):

> Make sure our SDK line is after all other 3rd-party SDK lines that install an exception handler. (We need to be last one called in your appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.)

Example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    //StatusBar
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    //NavBar 
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

    ...

    //Crashlytics
    //Make sure this SDK line is after all other 3rd-party SDK lines that install an exception handler.
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    return true
}
```

3) [If you're using our [Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/121064-why-don-t-i-see-data-from-my-first-crash-in-the-da)

> If you're using our [Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; to test crashing, make sure it's not in the appDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: 1. Debug information is DWARF with dSYM File”
2.removed other code just put the lines mentioned  3. used  [Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; code in a UIViewController (button click)   . the console show it crash uploaded successfully, but not in the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Every build that we get out of Xcode contains a DYsm file which contains definitions for all possible crashes, So you also need to upload that file to Firebase Console.

- I'm not 100% sure but I guess in development mode no crashes are uploaded to crashlytics, Only when the App is installed on the phone.